# Filtering on Measure value in PowerBI Matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have this table on Power BI:

```
    Day      Level1     Level2     Level3     Level4     Level5     Instances
02/02/2021    X23         C45        Y56        U56       O90         1384
12/06/2021    G21         Y22        N35        J46       K33         2454
23/08/2021    X23         C45                                          39
10/09/2021    G21         Y22        N35                               45 
   ...        ...         ...        ...        ...       ...          ...
```

I displayed a matrix with the 5 levels, where `Instances` are shown grouped by Level:

[image]

Then I proceeded to calculate the % of each level from the total, like following:

```
TotalInstances = SUM ( Table[Instances] )
```

And then:

```
PercentageAllLevels = 
VAR CurrentInstances = Table[TotalInstances]
VAR Level5Instances =
    CALCULATE ( [TotalInstances], ALLSELECTED ( Table[Level5] ) )
VAR Level4Instances =
    CALCULATE ( [TotalInstances], ALLSELECTED ( Table[Level4] ) )
VAR Level3Instances =
    CALCULATE ( [TotalInstances], ALLSELECTED ( Table[Level3] ) )
VAR Level2Instances =
    CALCULATE ( [TotalInstances], ALLSELECTED ( Table[Level2] ) )
VAR Level1Instances =
    CALCULATE ( [TotalInstances], ALLSELECTED ( Table[Level1] ) )
VAR RatioToParent =
    IF (
        ISINSCOPE ( Table[Level5] ),
        DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level5Instances ),
        IF (
            ISINSCOPE ( Table[Level4] ),
            DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level4Instances ),
            IF (
                ISINSCOPE ( Table[Level3] ),
                DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level3Instances ),
                IF (
                    ISINSCOPE ( Table[Level2] ),
                    DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level2Instances ),
                    IF (
                        ISINSCOPE ( Table[Level1] ),
                        DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level1Instances )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    RatioToParent
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I want to display only values where `PercentageAllLevels` is above 5%

But when I used Filters in PBI, the calculations were impacted.

Like following:

[image]

[image]

Is there a better way to exclude these values from being shown without impacting the calculations?

Thank you

Comment: what's a reson for ALLSELECTED ?

Comment: looks like Allexcept is a solution.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be greater than 5,0%? And as @Mik suggested you can try Allexcept.

Comment: @MinMin yes my bad it should be greater than. But even with ALLEXCEPT, the percentages are changing when the filter is applied.

Comment: @Mik I used AllExcept but the values still change with the filter. The change I did is like the following : `VAR Level5Instances =
    CALCULATE ( [TotalInstances], ALLEXCEPT( EVAR19_TEST, EVAR19_TEST[Level1],EVAR19_TEST[Level2],EVAR19_TEST[Level3], EVAR19_TEST[Level4] )` )

Comment: Hi @HelpASisterOut, try `VAR CurrentInstances = CALCULATE(Table[TotalInstances], ALL(Table))`.

Comment: If this will not help, please, add more data to your table, so, I can replicate the problem and think about solution.

Comment: @Mik It didnt work unfortunately. heres a link to sample data https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fec1806e5112423e019c37080e09490020220805131948/ad918a

Comment: Hi @HelpASisterOut. When you filter above 5%, do you want to filter only the higherest parent?

Comment: @Mik no I want to hide all values under 5%, my bad in the post i put the wrong screenshot. Now I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filter will not affect the measure. The problem is its behaviour - if you have for l1-l2-l3-l4-l5 values like 1%-2%-6%-3%-2% you will see values for l1-l2 also, because l3 extention has >5%. And if you have l5>5% then the line will not be filtered. If you need another behaviour, then, please, specify the result with more details.

```
PercentageAllLevelsSwitch = 

VAR CurrentInstances = [TotalInstances]
VAR Level4Instances =
    CALCULATE([TotalInstances],ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level4],'Table'[Level3],'Table'[Level2],'Table'[Level1]))
VAR Level3Instances =
    CALCULATE([TotalInstances],ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level3],'Table'[Level2],'Table'[Level1]))
VAR Level2Instances =
    CALCULATE([TotalInstances],ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level2],'Table'[Level1]))
VAR Level1Instances =
    CALCULATE([TotalInstances],ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Level1]))    
VAR RatioToParent =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE()
        ,ISINSCOPE ( 'Table'[Level5] ),DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level4Instances )
        ,ISINSCOPE ( 'Table'[Level4] ),DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level3Instances )
        ,ISINSCOPE ( 'Table'[Level3] ),DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level2Instances )
        ,ISINSCOPE ( 'Table'[Level2] ),DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, Level1Instances )
        ,DIVIDE ( CurrentInstances, CALCULATE([TotalInstances],ALL('Table')))
    )
RETURN
    RatioToParent
```